# Uncaught TypeError: .slideToggle is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jquery in a different file located in the same map, I'm using this code below to activate the `.slideToggle` function. However it's not working, why?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // get li items
    var ul = document.getElementById("menu-footermenu");
    var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    // display 5 li items, hide others
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        if (i > 5) {
            items[i].style.display = "none"
        }
    }

    // when clicking on more catogories button, display all items
    $('#morecat').click(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
            if (i > 5) {
                items[i].slideToggle();
                document.getElementById("morecat").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: .slideToggle is not a function

Comment: Goto 2nd Answer for solution

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly ensure you're not using the 'slim' branch of jQuery as it does not include animation or AJAX functionality, amongst others. You will need to use the full version of jQuery in this instance.

In addition, `items` in your code will be a collection of Element objects, not jQuery objects, hence the `slideToggle()` function is not available on them.

To fix this you need to convert them:

```
$(items[i]).slideToggle();
```

Alternatively, you can convert all the logic to use jQuery, instead of the rather odd half/half solution you have now:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  var $ul = $("#menu-footermenu");
  var $items = $("li");
  $items.filter(':gt(4)').hide();

  $('#morecat').click(function () {
    $items.filter(':gt(4)').slideToggle();
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Glad to help. I updated the answer with a pure jQuery solution too.

Comment: I did, needed to wait a few minutes.

Answer (score 49):

make sure, NOT to use the **slim** version of jquery, which excludes the effects like the animation.

Comment: that was my problem too.